# Excluding specific directory in tar using --exclude

Tags: syntax, tar, macos-monterey

Imagine the following dir structure:

```
tartest> find .
.
./node_modules
./foo
./foo/node_modules
./foo/foo.js
```

Is there a way to exclude the top-level node_modules but not the one under `foo` using **only** tar (not a find/xargs solution).

I would have thought specifying the excluded directory using `./node_modules` would work but

```
tartest> tar cvfz ../foo.tar.gz  --exclude='./node_modules' .
a .
a ./foo
a ./foo/foo.js
```

Comment: May be different based on the version of `tar` you're using...could you post `tar --version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar cvfz ../foo.tar.gz  --exclude='^./node_modules' .
```

since `--exclude` takes a pattern. It remains to be seen if the '^' as beginning-of-line match is valid for your version of `tar`.

Comment: This works on my MacOS 12.1-Monterey, bsdtar 3.5.1.